# Javascript Object Prototype Reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

As per my knowledge, the second case below should be true, but in fact it is false.  So why is it not true?

**Case 1**

```
     var P = function(){};
         P.prototype.get = function(){};

    var p = new P,q = new P;        
    console.log(q.__proto__ === p.__proto__) //true
```

**Case 2**

```
var PP = function(){
    var P = function(){};
    P.prototype.get = function(){};
    return new P;
};

var p = PP(), q = PP();
console.log(q.__proto__ === p.__proto__) //false
```

Comment: Thanks Geeks, I found the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, `P` and `get()` are predefined globals.  In the second, they're local to the function that defines PP, hence, a different reference for each instance.

Answer (score 2):

In the top one, you have a `new P`.

In the second, you have `new P` in the function and then take `new` of that function.

This might screw it up.

Nevermind, it's because of the global vars, like he said.

Comment: Extra new was my mistake (in 2 case). p and q objects are not equal even after removed the extra new

Comment: @Ganesh Kumar- If you remove the second new it checks out for me

Answer (score 2):

In the first case `var p = new P,q = new P;` both instantiated the global `P` and it's prototype so it returns true.

In the second case `q` and `p` are both different objects instantiated using `new PP` which returned different `P` from inside `PP` function using `return new P`. So it returns false.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it, what you asked ?

Comment: I already read that book. small confusion with prototype stuff. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's really sometimes confuses me too because it's really confusing, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the `PP` function you create a new function object each time that is called `P`. Each one of those functions has a different prototype.